# How to test for existence of a file on the Puppet Master

Tags: ruby, linux, puppet

In a customized modules on Puppet I have

```
g_iptables
├── files
│   └── fqdn-of-server
├── lib
│   └── puppet
│       └── parser
│           └── functions
│               └── file_exists.rb
└── manifests
    └── init.pp
```

and I want to let the module do something whether or not the file "fqdn-of-server" exist on the Puppet Master. Googling did get me a file_exists.rb function:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'puppet'

module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:file_exists, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
    if File.exists?(args[0])
      return 1
    else
      return 0
    end
  end
end
```

and this does work when put in something like:

```
$does_fqdn_file_exists = file_exists("/tmp/$fqdn")

if $does_fqdn_file_exists == 1 {
 ...
}
```

in my manifest init.pp (of course $fqdn is a facter). The problem is that it works only on the client (so $does_fqdn_file_exists is 1 if the /tmp/$fqdn exist on the client $fqdn, it does not work on the puppet master.

Also, I want to use puppet:/// uri structures in this construct, but thus sofar, my function doesn't understand this uri.

Can somebody help me ? The ruby function stems from someone on the web, who claims that it checks the file existence on the master, which is not the case (at least not what I can see).

Comment: You can use exist() function
https://gist.github.com/j4m3s/3307835
I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the puppet master you could test it like this:

```
# create a temporary file that may look like this :

]$ cat /tmp/checkfile.pp
$does_fqdn_file_exists = file_exists("/tmp/$fqdn")
notify{ "Check File = $does_fqdn_file_exists" : }

# Then run it :

]$ puppet apply /tmp/checkfile.pp
```

Answer (score 4):

Alex G provided solution with some corrections works for me, and maybe will be useful for someone else:

```
if file('/does/it/exist', '/dev/null') != '' {
    # /does/it/exist must exist, do things here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do with with the standard function library.  Make a file in a known location with the content "not found", and use this check:

```
if file('/does/it/exist', '/file/containing/not_found') != 'not found' {
    # /does/it/exist must exist, do things here
}
```

This is because the [`file()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.17/function.html#file) function in Puppet will read the contents of the first file provided that actually exists.  Kind of a kludge to use it this way, but it works and doesn't require modifying the default set of functions.